# Apache Mod Rewrite

Tags: apache, apache-modules

Подскажите, как настроить в апаче, чтобы при обращении на site.ru/page.asp выполнялся page.php? То есть подменялось расширение файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexp?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.asp$ $1.php
```